# Access to ArcGIS classify range labels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Is it possible to access to the range labels set within Layer Properties > Symbology tab? (see image)[image: screengrab of layer properties]

I have numerous layers with different class ranges and would like to export range values as plain text to use elsewhere, rather than ctrl-c ctrl-v for each class in each layer.

**UPDATE**

Following the pointer from @Vince I've tried the following ArcPy script built through advice at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/labelclass-class.htm

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"path\to\my_mxd.mxd")

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
        for lblClass in lyr.labelClasses:
            print "Layer name: " + lyr.name
            print "    Expression:  " + lblClass.expression

del mxd
```

But `lblClass.expression` doesn't access the labels needed. Is there another property I can access? Can't see a suitable one in ArcPy classes `LabelClass` or `Layer`.

Comment: You'll need to write a dozen lines of Python using `arcpy.mapping`, but yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but a hint to the code above:
It has nothing to do with labes (in terms of "labeling of a layer"), i fear, but with the layers symbology and the list property classBreakLabels as lyr.symbology.classBreakLabels.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    try:
        for clbrkLabel in lyr.symbology.classBreakLabels:
            print clbrkLabel
    except NameError as e:
        print lyr.name, e
    except AttributeError as e:
        print lyr.name, e
```

prints out the TOC's labels, if symbology supports this...

Comment: Accepting this answer. Layer symbology is where to go.

Comment: In this sample, to change the labels use `=` where now printing, e.g. `lyr.symbology.classBreakLabels = ["Label 1", Label 2", ...]`. This changes all labels at once and needs to exactly match the list length of the classes breaks.